# How to integrate Stripe Connect to rails without Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments

I have been trying for a week to integrate Stripe connect to my website. I am working on creating an e-commerce website where users can buy and sell products. I already have a user model and a product model. I've worked a bit on authentication so I am apprehensive about using Devise. However, I am relatively new to rails so I have mainly been looking online for tutorials on integrating the systems. All the tutorials I have found require devise. I would really appreciate any recommendations or tips on adding Stripe connect to my site without using devise. Thanks!

Comment: The [pay gem](https://github.com/pay-rails/pay) is relatively new but could be just what you are looking for to do just this. There is also a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKWq_soCzsQ).

Answer (score 0):

The [official Stripe Ruby library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/) has full support for Connect and does not require Devise.

As far as tutorials go, maybe try one of the following:

- https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/rails/stripe/stripe-connect-part-1.html
- https://medium.com/@ThatGuyTinus/stripe-connect-rails-part-1-22ba7204725b